# Working with lists in pandas: apply(pd.Series) doesn't work - an alternative solution?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a data set structured like this:

```
mydic = {'2017-9-11': {'Type1': [15, 115452.0, 3], 'Type2': [47, 176153.0, 4], 'Type3': [0, 0, 0]}, '2017-9-12': {'Type1': [26, 198223.0, 5], 'Type2': [39, 178610.0, 6], 'Type3': [0, 0, 0]}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydic, orient='index')
```

I need to split values in the lists into different columns and group them by Types. This is what I do:

```
df_new = df[list(df)].unstack().apply(pd.Series)
df_new.head()
```

And it works:

```
                    0       1           2
Type1   2017-9-11   15.0    115452.0    3.0
        2017-9-12   26.0    198223.0    5.0
Type3   2017-9-11   0.0     0.0         0.0
        2017-9-12   0.0     0.0         0.0
Type2   2017-9-11   47.0    176153.0    4.0
```

BUT when I apply this code to a larger real-life data set it seems like `apply(pd.Series)` doesn't work and I get just one column 0 with lists of values like this:

```
                    0    
Type1  2017-9-11    [15, 115452.0, 3]
       2017-9-12    [26, 198223.0, 5]
Type2  2017-9-11    [47, 176153.0, 4]
       2017-9-12    [39, 178610.0, 6]
Type3  2017-9-11            [0, 0, 0]
```

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong? Or suggest an alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It think faster solution is `DataFrame` constructor, see [timings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35491399/2901002):

```
s = df.unstack()
df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index)
print (df)
                  0         1  2
Type1 2017-9-11  15  115452.0  3
      2017-9-12  26  198223.0  5
Type2 2017-9-11  47  176153.0  4
      2017-9-12  39  178610.0  6
Type3 2017-9-11   0       0.0  0
      2017-9-12   0       0.0  0
```

EDIT:

If values are strings:

```
df = df.unstack().str.strip('[]').str.split(', ', expand=True).astype(float)
print (df)
                    0         1    2
Type1 2017-9-11  15.0  115452.0  3.0
      2017-9-12  26.0  198223.0  5.0
Type2 2017-9-11  47.0  176153.0  4.0
      2017-9-12  39.0  178610.0  6.0
Type3 2017-9-11   0.0       0.0  0.0
      2017-9-12   0.0       0.0  0.0
```

Or is possible convert values to `list`s:

```
import ast

s = df.unstack().apply(ast.literal_eval)
df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index).astype(float)
print (df)
                    0         1    2
Type1 2017-9-11  15.0  115452.0  3.0
      2017-9-12  26.0  198223.0  5.0
Type2 2017-9-11  47.0  176153.0  4.0
      2017-9-12  39.0  178610.0  6.0
Type3 2017-9-11   0.0       0.0  0.0
      2017-9-12   0.0       0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Hi, the df constructor gives me the same result - one column "0" with lists of values. When I use s[0] as you suggested it doesn't change anything - still one column. There is probably something wrong with my larger dataset...

Comment: Are values `lists` ? What return `print (df.applymap(type))` ?

Comment: It returns `<type 'str'>`... So I have strings there.

Comment: Converting back to list worked! Thanks! But the option for strings using `df.unstack().str.strip('[]').str.split(', ', expand=True).astype(float)` gives me this error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'`

Comment: What is `print (df.unstack().columns)` ? It seems unstack return DataFrame, not Series.

Comment: I restarted the notebook and it worked this time. I most probably converted something at some point... So both options work! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

For Data frame , point out witch columns to apply for .

```
df.unstack().to_frame()[0].apply(pd.Series)

Out[545]: 
                    0         1    2
Type2 2017-9-11  47.0  176153.0  4.0
      2017-9-12  39.0  178610.0  6.0
Type1 2017-9-11  15.0  115452.0  3.0
      2017-9-12  26.0  198223.0  5.0
Type3 2017-9-11   0.0       0.0  0.0
      2017-9-12   0.0       0.0  0.0
```

Break done :

```
df1=df.unstack().to_frame()
df1
Out[546]: 
                                 0
Type2 2017-9-11  [47, 176153.0, 4]
      2017-9-12  [39, 178610.0, 6]
Type1 2017-9-11  [15, 115452.0, 3]
      2017-9-12  [26, 198223.0, 5]
Type3 2017-9-11          [0, 0, 0]
      2017-9-12          [0, 0, 0]
```

then do `apply` :

df1[0].apply(pd.Series)

```
Out[550]: 
                    0         1    2
Type2 2017-9-11  47.0  176153.0  4.0
      2017-9-12  39.0  178610.0  6.0
Type1 2017-9-11  15.0  115452.0  3.0
      2017-9-12  26.0  198223.0  5.0
Type3 2017-9-11   0.0       0.0  0.0
      2017-9-12   0.0       0.0  0.0
```

Comment: may be `df.unstack().apply(ast.literal_eval).to_frame()[0].apply(pd.Series)` OP said they are strings